# I want to build a minimap for my HTML5 game, how do I start?

Tags: javascript, html

Assume I have a big map which uses a background image as pattern. I want to place a minimap at the corner when I am moving the player around. All I need the minimap to do is to display where my player is in the big map and where are other sprites in the map, using a very coarse representation and keeping their relative location but shows everything in a much smaller map. So I think this is a very basic and simple minimap. My player will be in the middle of the screen (I have already done that) and the minimap will stay at the corner of the screen. If I want to build such a feature for my game, how do I start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your main map is in a container element, you need to measure the scroll property of that element to establish at what position it is relative to the center of the container (or screen). [image]

If you calculate the x and y as a proportion (eg %) of the map, you can then place something on the mini map at the same relative position.

The placing of the mini map over the main map is of no importance.

To get the position of the map relative to the screen, try `document.getElementById("map").getBoundingClientRect()`. The x and y values in the resulting array tell you the position of the top left of the map from the top left of the screen. The width and height of the map are also included in the array. Add `screen.width/2` and `screen height/2` to get the coordinates of the map in the center of the screen.

Comment: Thanks this does the job!